# How can you get Maven enforcer plugin to not report dependency convergence errors twice?

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

Consider the following example:

```
[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.4 paths to dependency are:
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-http-client:3.0.2
      +-com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:3.9.0
        +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.4
and
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-commons:3.0.2
      +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.8
and
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-commons:3.0.2
      +-com.dongxiguo:fastring_2.12:1.0.0
        +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.1
and
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-commons:3.0.2
      +-com.softwaremill.quicklens:quicklens_2.12:1.4.11
        +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.3

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.4 paths to dependency are:
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-http-client:3.0.2
      +-com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:3.9.0
        +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.4
and
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-commons:3.0.2
      +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.8
and
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-commons:3.0.2
      +-com.dongxiguo:fastring_2.12:1.0.0
        +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.1
and
+-com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:0.9.2
  +-io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2
    +-io.gatling:gatling-commons:3.0.2
      +-com.softwaremill.quicklens:quicklens_2.12:1.4.11
        +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.3
]
```

Both of those warnings are the same convergence error. The second one is a summary of the preceding warnings, reporting an array of the errors previously found. However, this just creates a lot of excess visual noise. This example isn't all that painful, but when you have several convergence errors it becomes quite a mess. I haven't had any success searching the docs for a way to get the plugin to only report this stuff once -- is this possible?

(NB this is maven-enforcer-plugin v. 1.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be that the plugin hasn't had a formal "stable" release in a while. Upgrading to 3.0.0-M2 switches this so the error message says "Hey, you had some errors. See above."